# Relation between the sample size with the powers of Kolmogorov Smirnov, Cramer Von Mises and Anderson Darling?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, statistical-power, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

I want to know the mathematical relation between the sample size with the powers of 1. Kolmogorov Smirnov, 2. Cramer Von Mises, and 3. Anderson Darling.

I have seen many posts and other websites saying that the power of these tests decreases when the sample size is small but can we derive a mathematical relation between the power and sample size?

Comment: That's going to depend on the null and the alternative, I'm afraid.

Comment: Almost all (quite possibly all) of the hypothesis tests you'll have seen have the property that as you increase sample size, the power increases (*holding other things equal*), and as you decrease sample size, the power decreases (*ditto*). With something like a one sample z-test this is straightforward to quantify algebraically and still pretty doable with say a t-test, but harder with an omnibus EDF-based test (and as jbowman says, depends on the alternative). You could, naturally simulate the situation for a specific alternative at a sequence of sample sizes and see it that way.